# Consola de comandos en cpanel NO MUESTRA SALIDA Magento2

Tags: magento2

Buenas gente recién comencé a trabajar con Magento 2, ya me hice de varias pruebas locales en entorno DEV para comenzar, pero me entraron unas dudas de principiante.
Al ejecutar comandos como `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, en un entorno de producción en mi caso la consola de C PANEL, no me muestra ninguna salida.
Mi pregunta es:
Existe alguna manera de solucionar este inconveniente, ya que ademas de todo no obtengo resultados en mi sitio, aun borrando caché y cerrando el cliente de magento2.
[image: Resultado de la consola]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve batallando mucho con este tema ya que no hay mucha información acerca de los posibles errores que tiene la consola, finalmente encontre la solución y la comparto:

Al correr cada comando es necesario añadir la linea : `-dmemory_limit=1G`.

Al añadir esta linea efectivamente los comandos se ejecutarán:
[image: Solución de ejecución de comandos -Prueba-]